# Regex to find exact match in a string works elsewhere but not on MySql Query

Tags: mysql, regex, string, exact-match

The given string is a comma separated value, for example the string below

```
29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,192,225,228,233,239,240,144,145
```

I want to find the exact whole match of any number in the string, and I did write a regex to find it. When I checked it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UP8mIV/1), it worked well. But when I wrote the same regex on MySql Query, it did not work

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (value REGEXP '.*\b22\b,{0,1}.*')
```

I did find another query that works, it used concat() function.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(',',value,',') like '%,22,%'
```

Edit: The answer from @anubhava also works (which can be found on the very first comment on this question). Since I am able to pick only one answer as Solved, I just wanted to let others know.

Thanks again

Comment: Try: `value REGEXP '.*\\b22\\b.*'`

Comment: @anubhava I think this is a syntax API issue, not a regex problem.

Comment: When I open your regex101 it tells me "no match". So how does this work well?

Comment: @anubhava: If that addresses me: I didn't claim that...

Comment: @stickybit, yes it should show that as there is not 22, it should only find the exact word, in this case 22, and not 22 in 225 and in 228. But if you put just 22 separated with comma anywhere, it will work

Comment: @stickybit: No, not addressed to you. regex101 was mentioned in question

Comment: @anubhava, yes this worked.. thanks.. so escaping "\" was the answer...

Comment: @theNewbie: Ah OK, that explains it. I didn't realize ",22," was missing.

Comment: Yes double escaping `\b` or `\d`, `\w` etc is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your version of MySQL, most likely word boundaries are denoted by `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE value REGEXP '[[:<:]]22[[:>:]]';
```

I believe that starting with MySQL 8+, it is possible to use the more standard `\b` to represent a word boundary.  Check the demo link below to see it working on MySQL 5.7.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

There is a function just for this task:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('22', '29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,192,225,228,233,239,240,144,145')
```